# Integración de DLLs .NET en python

Tags: python, .net, dll

Me gustaría cargar unas librerías DLL en mi proyecto python puesto que necesito ejecutar un .exe que hace uso de dichas librerías, pero tengo un error. Básicamente, lo que tengo es:

```
dllfiles = os.listdir('modules/dlls')
for dllfile in dllfiles:
    ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(dllfile)
```

Eso para cargar la librería, posteriormente, lo que quiero es:

`subprocess.run(["modules/exe/fileExe.exe", "-config param1 param2"])`

Sin embargo, cuando ejecuto, tengo el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bim2beps.py", line 47, in <module>
    ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(ctypes.CDLL(dllfile))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado
```

Me gustaría saber cuál puede ser el problema al cargar la librería. Además, si hay alguna otra forma de que esas librerías estén disponibles al ejecutar el fichero exe. Es decir, es el fileExe.exe el que necesita tener las DLLs disponibles.

Gracias por adelantado

Comment: En este caso... no, según me lo han pasado van separadas, de hecho si lo ejecuto (incluso fuera de python) me salta el error que no encuentra las DLLs. En particular, obtengo una excepción de "FileNotFound" porque no encuentra una de las librerías de la DLL

Comment: Están en la misma carpeta. Lo que estoy haciendo, si he entendido bien lo que he leído es utilizar una librería dll para ejecutar alguna función. Y yo lo que necesito es que estén en el path, ¿verdad?

Comment: Muchas gracias por los comentarios, sinceramente me extrañó que me pasaran un ejecutable y que no tuviera las librerías... sino tendré que intentar ir a la fuente del error (la persona que me pasó el exe jajaja)

Comment: ¿Seguro que son librerías dll de C? Si son de *.NET* puede que estés utilizando *ctypes* cuando deberías echar un vistazo a [PythonNET](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet). Quizás son librerías escritas en *C#* y compiladas a *CIL*. Un saludo.